# When is a ReadOnly Variable allocated?

Tags: c#

An online test has this question:

Features of Read Only Variable:

1. It is allocated at compile time
2. Declaration and initialization is separated
3. It is allocated at runtime
4. All of these

The test gave the answer as 4. I get 2 and 3 but not sure about 1. Would this be an example of when the answer of 1 could occur:

```
private readonly int readonlyExample = 10;
```

Note: I would normally use a const for the example above

Comment: Interesting question, but a poor choice of answers to choose from.

Comment: that is not a very good question.

Comment: I agree. Poor choice of answers. Where is this online test? It is allocated at compile time.. but that's only because the compiler doesn't substitute it throughout the codebase.. that is confusing for some though.

Comment: http://www.careerride.com/Csharp-net-practice-online-test.aspx

Comment: Terrible suite of tests. Question: "Content of assembly can be viewed using:". Possible answers: "ILDASM.exe", "ILDASM.dll", "ILDASM.inc", "ILDASM.aspx"... seriously?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yeah, I had a run at it. Pretty lame stuff "In C#, by default structs are passed how?" What does C# have to do with this? Why are you quizzing people on an implementation detail?

Comment: @vcsjones " Is there any errors in this -> EmployeeMgmt constructor: Public int EmployeeMgmt { emp_id = 100; }". Obviously it has no parenthesis.. but it also has an uppercase P on the access modifier. I'm scared for the people who use this website to learn.

Comment: A colleague prepared a theory test for some interviews we are holding. I agree there are some silly questions in there. I'm preparing the practical exam for 2nd interviews, much more fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These possible answers are a bit confusing (in my opinion).

What is actually going on is the C# compiler actually emits something like this:

```
private readonly int readOnlyExample;

public YourClassConstructor()
{
    this.readOnlyExample = 10;
}
```

Given that, #2 seems like a possible choice. The declaration and assignment are separated. (What they even mean by that is up for grabs)

3 is also possibly correct because the value has to live in memory *somewhere*. It isn't a compile time constant.

Comment: So you are saying my example is still allocated at runtime and the answer of 4 is just wrong? If so, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you assigned a value to readonly variable then you are binding variable then this is compile time. For example:

```
readonlt int xyz=10; // then this is compile time
```

If you are assigning value from any function that will execute and return value then it will be Run Time. For example:

```
readonly int xyz=objClass.getSum();  // Then it is runtime.
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer (4) is not correct. 
Because, option 1) is not correct!!

Readonly field doesnt has to be a compile time value. 
Consider the following code, and it compiles well even though the value assigned to readonly field is not a compile time known value!!

```
    public class ValidatingReadonlyField
{
    private readonly UnKnownClass _readonlyField = new UnKnownClass();
}
public class UnKnownClass
{
    private object _someValue;

    public UnKnownClass()
    {
        _someValue = GetMeSomeThing();
    }

    private static object GetMeSomeThing()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can you call me at Compile Time!!!");
    }
}
```

Edit: Updating as per @Renae comments:

@Renae: Answer 1 is Not Correct! Because, the example above explains a scenario where readonly variable is *not* allocated at compile time. And hence, negating statement 1. 
If you want to negate further, try replacing readonly with "const" and the compile will tell you that it could only have compile time values (which is not a pre-condition for readonly).

Comment: Hi, yes i understand this, your example covers answers 2 and 3 but as the answer was 4, I was asking if or when answer 1 could occur.

Comment: @Renae: added more details, trying to answer you comments.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info but this still doesn't answer my question. The answer implies that a readonly can be allocated at compile time and runtime. Your example proves 2 and 3 are true but does not conclusively say that 1 is not true. My example could be a const, is the c# compilier smart enough to see this and treat it like a const? vcsjones answer tells me it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword readonly has a value that may be changed or assigned at runtime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).